# How to change order of words in a string?

Tags: c#, string

I'm a real newbie and whilst I found a question and answer quite similar ([Winforms C# change string text order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534021/winforms-c-sharp-change-string-text-order)) I  still need some help with this please, especially due to point 3 below which makes it a bit more tricky.

1. The string is made up of 3 'Words' the order of which needs to be changed. The string always has the same pattern: "WordOne WordTwo WordThree" - some examples are "Car Storage Sydney", "Boat Storage Melbourne" and "Caravan Storage Brisbane".
2. Each 'Word' is separated always by a single space. As I understand this would be used to split the variable up and then it could be re-formatted to achieve the desired order change (see 4 below)
3. This is where it gets a bit tricky: The 3rd 'Word' sometimes is actually two words, ie "Word Three" instead of "WordThree" perhaps better explained with another example: "Boat Storage Gold Coast"
4. The desired order change is "WordThree WordOne WordTwo" (basically, just moving "WordThree" from the back to the front) so using the same examples as in 1 above, the finished result would be "Sydney Car Storage", "Melbourne Boat Storage" and "Brisbane Caravan Storage". And the tricky one, based on the sometimes two-worded "Word Three", as shown in 3. above, would be "Gold Coast Boat Storage"

I hope I have explained it well enough.

Except for issue as described in 3. above, I believe it should be something like this, just my rough newbie attempt at the code:

```
string wordsBefore = "WordOne WordTwo WordThree";
string[] wordsWorking = wordsBefore.Split(new string[]{" "});
string wordsAfter = ("{0} {1} {2}", wordsWorking[2], wordsWorking[0], wordsWorking[1]);
```

I think this is pretty close?

But of course, because of issue as described in 3. above, there needs to be additional code to detect when "WordThree" contains two words and to somehow handle them as one word. I think you know what I mean!

Eagerly awaiting some assistance!

Comment: Have a look at the [Stack Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx).

Comment: @Brian considering the 4th point of the OP I don't think the Stack will help.

Comment: Why is "Foo Bar Baz" three word and "Foo Bar Baz Qux" too? If you can explain that, you can solve this. If your grouped words have something in common, you could add a check for that. For example a fixed list of word combinations. But if output 1 always needs to be input 3 (and onwards), this one isn't too hard to crack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell `Split` to only give you a certain number of results:

```
string wordsBefore = "WordOne WordTwo Word Three";
string[] wordsWorking = wordsBefore.Split(new [] {' '}, 3);
string wordsAfter = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", 
                wordsWorking[2], wordsWorking[0], wordsWorking[1]);

// result: "Word Three WordOne WordTwo"
```

Or if you want to be clever with `String.Format`:

```
string wordsBefore = "WordOne WordTwo Word Three";
string[] wordsWorking = wordsBefore.Split(new [] {' '}, 3);
string wordsAfter = string.Format("{2} {0} {1}", wordsWorking);
```

Comment: Thanks D Stanley, this worked (the second one):
`string wordsBefore = "WordOne WordTwo Word Three";
string[] wordsWorking = wordsBefore.Split(new [] {' '}, 3);
string wordsAfter = string.Format("{2} {0} {1}", wordsWorking);`

Answer (score 3):

```
string wordsBefore = "WordOne WordTwo WordThree";
string[] wordsWorking = wordsBefore.Split();
string wordsAfter = ("{0} {1} {2}", string.Join(" ", wordsWorking.Skip(2)), wordsWorking[0], wordsWorking[1]);
```

Comment: Sorry Austin, this didn't work. I tried it with my actual code on a live site and got an error. Sorry I am not advanced enough to explain what the error was... @d-stanley 's answer did work however.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple.

```
string wordsBefore = "WordOne WordTwo WordThree";
string[] wordsWorking = wordsBefore.Split(new string[]{" "});
string word1 = wordsWorking[0];
string word2 = wordsWorking[1];
string word3 = wordsWorking[2];

if (wordsWorking.length == 4)
   word3 = word3 + " " + wordsWorking[3];

string wordsAfter = ("{0} {1} {2}", word3 word1, word2);
```

Comment: thanks henk, this looks great and the simple approach especially good for my basic level of understanding of programming. in this case however I had already tested @D Stanley's answer which works perfectly so I will run with that. i'm sure this one would work perfectly as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
const string wordsBefore = "WordOne WordTwo Word Three";
string[] wordsWorking = wordsBefore.Split();
var thirdWord = wordsWorking.Skip(2).Aggregate((s, s1) => s + " " + s1);    
string wordsAfter = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", thirdWord, wordsWorking[0], wordsWorking[1]);
```

Comment: thanks Petrutiu, appreciate your answer although I did not test it as I am satisfied with @D Stanley's above, but thanks anyway. wow, this site is amazing, so much support out there!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example:

```
string text = "word one<splittag>word two and some other words<splittag>word three with   some text";
        string[] words = text.Split(new string[] { "<splittag>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Label1.Text = String.Format("{2},{0},{1}", words[2], words[0], words[1]);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: wow thanks. i did not get to even try this as @D Stanley's answer worked perfectly for me, but thanks anyway